# Selenium IE9 - OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When running a `selenium` based test on `IE 9`, I see the following exception raised for an element that does exist on the webpage:

> An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchWindowException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

This error does not occur on `Chrome` for example.

Does anyone know why this would occur and what the resolution to this is?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are trying with?

Answer (score 0):

Try to complete next steps from [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration).

"On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode"."

At my case this exception was raised when I was not completed this step.